# Rename Indices when restoring snapshot in Elasticsearch, drop characters from index name

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I am trying to rename some ES indices while restoring a buckup. I would like to drop some characters while doing it, e.g if my index is *my_es_index-2022-10_tmp* I would like to to be renamed  to *new_index-10* I am using this command to get this

curl -u -XPOST http://my-es-cluster/_snapshot/snapshot-repo/snapshot/*restore -d'
{
"indices": "my_es_index-2022-10_tmp",
"ignore_unavailable": true,
"include_global_state": false,
"rename_pattern": "(.+)",
"rename_replacement": new*"$1"
}'

can anyone help me get the values for rename_pattern and rename_replacement? I've tryied several combination but I couldn't drop the part of index I want

Answer (score 1):

Since you're restoring a single index you don't need to mess with regular expressions, just rename it to what you want:

```
{ 
   "indices": "my_es_index-2022-10_tmp", 
   "ignore_unavailable": true, 
   "include_global_state": false, 
   "rename_pattern": "(.+)", 
   "rename_replacement": "new_index-10"
}
```